# Error when adding error message to offset cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that looks up a list of IDs and compares them against another list in another tab. I would like to print the error message ", Payer Id is not setup" into column A and add it to whatever is already in that cell.

I am getting an error message "object required" on the "a.offset(0,-1) = cell.offset......." line.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set A = Range("B2")

    Do Until IsEmpty(A)

        Set B = Worksheets("payorTab").Range("A4")
        Do Until B.Value = A.Value Or IsEmpty(B)
            Set B = B.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        If IsEmpty(B) Then
            A.Offset(0, -1) = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & ", Payer ID is not setup"
        End If

        Set A = A.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I would like the error message to concatenate to whatever is already in the cell in column A.

Comment: When do you set `cell` in `cell.Offset()`? `Cell` needs to refer to a range object, but you never assigned a range to it anywhere in the visible code you provided.

Comment: This can also be done much more efficiently. Instead of calling the worksheet object every time you want to look at a cell's value - same with writing values back to the worksheet (as well as causing many events to fire), place the values into an array - compare the array - write to the array - then when you are completely finished write the array back to the worksheet.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and declare all your variables with an explicit data type. `cell` is undefined, so `.Offset` is made against a `Variant/Empty` - hence "object required": `Variant/Empty` isn't an object you can make member calls against.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I solved it by replacing the cell.offset with a.offset